# Java offset encoding

Tags: java, encoding, offset

Write a program that takes in a string and an integer offset.  In this program we want to encode the string by increasing each character by the integer offset in alphabetical order. So if the integer offset t given is 1, b becomes c. Furthermore, M becomes N, and z becomes a.

Comment: ... and you want us to write that program, right?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free homework service.

Comment: @user3566914 I've answered your question providing a description of a way to solve your problem as well as potential sources to look at for further research. Let me know if you need any additional help.

Answer (score 0):

I won't write the program for you, but here are a few (helpful) hints to get the ball rolling:

1. Look up the data type `char` and wrapper class `Character`. Read up on them and their representation in ASCII
2. Try using the `java.lang.String` method `toCharArray()` to break up the input string into an array of characters
3. After you have the array of characters, based on your ASCII knowledge, decide how to increment/decrement each character by a specified value in order to attain the result.
4. Remember to check for the edge cases (`'z'` becomes `'a'`, etc.) and convert the `Character[]` array to a `String`

Let me know if any of this doesn't make sense. Hopefully this answer will allow you to both understand and learn more intricate aspects of Java while at the same time writing and implementing your own code.